# sapui5 not load on iPhone and iPad

Tags: sapui5

I wrote a very simple UI5 app, but the callback of **window.alert("UI5 loaded")** is not called in iPhone and iPad.
Only **window.alert("UI5 step1")** is called.

It works on desktop and android browsers.

I must have made a stupid mistake. Anyone has met such a problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
        <title>UI5 Renderer</title>
        <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize_plus"
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-preload="async">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
            window.alert("UI5 loaded");
        });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
         <script type="text/javascript">
        window.alert("UI5 step1");
        </script>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason, I need to add below to make iphone works.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```